# Cannot complete these Windows updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I've the following updates pending on my system (approximate translation, I don't have Windows in english). But they can never be installed properly, after several attempts my computer at most manages to install them up to a 12% and then has to undo changes.

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 for Windows 10 Version 1703 of x64 (KB4486129)

2018-10 Cumulative update for Windows 10 Version 1703 para x64 based systems (KB4462937)

2018-08 Windows 10 Version 1703 update for x64 based systems (KB4073543)

Windows 10 Version 1703 update for x64 based systems (KB4033631)

My computer has been able to make other updates, but no matter how much those ones are tried, they are never installed after reboot.

What could I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be stuck in Windows 10 Version 1703, no longer supported by Microsoft.

I suggest, instead of updating this old version, to upgrade Windows to the
latest version that is suggested by your Settings utility at
*Update & Security > Windows Update*.

If no higher version than 1703 is to be found in there, you will need to
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This involves downloading the latest version suggested by Microsoft in
[Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Note that sometimes version 1703 cannot directly update to the latest version.
In such a case you will need to download and install the latest version 1803
available on [Tech Bench by WZT](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php).
You might even need to repeat this for version 1909.

If upgrading from Windows fails, you may need to do offline upgrade by booting
from Safe mode.